# Access object property using array syntax in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Does somebody know why accessing an object's property using array syntax works in some php versions but not others?

In the following line of code from the Amazon PHP SDK they do this and seems not to work in my dev server but works fine in my local server and production server

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Aws/Common/Client/UploadBodyListener.php#L75

PHP
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.13 with Suhosin-Patch (cli)

Error:

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Guzzle\Common\Event as array in /mnt/var/www/dev3.pearup.com/common/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Client/UploadBodyListener.php on line 75

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by implementing an [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php).

So the object you send to that function should also be an ArrayObject.

Comment: It looks like the Event object implementes the ArrayAccess interface
http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php

I wonder if my php setup is missing something

Comment: Did you try sending in an ArrayObject? It might work right away. ArrayAccess is available after > 5 so it should work directly, but maybe something else is going on.

Comment: The code is not written by me, is from the AWS PHP SDK.
I tracked it down to here https://github.com/guzzle/common/blob/master/Event.php#L10

The event class implements the ArrayAccess interface so i don't understand why this is not working on my dev server